# How to find an active record that only has 1 association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

`Foo` has many `Bar`s - how do I find a `Foo` that only has 1 `Bar`

`Foo.where(bars_count == 1).limit(1)` only gives me a Active Record Relation instead of a `Foo`

Comment: Minimally, `=` != `==`.

Comment: Try this `Foo.joins(:bars).group('foos.id').having('count(bars.id) = 1').limit(1).first`

Comment: `bars_count == 1` => `bars_count: 1` (assuming that field exists)